# Antonym for "optimize" in software development context

Tags: programming-languages, software-design

In the context of "optimizing" a set of data to a smaller, more compact form, what would be a word that would best describe its opposite (expanding data into a more usable form).

The only one I could come up with was "expand", but that's a better antonym of "compress", not "optimize"... any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this data context, "unfolding" may work, I'm just not 100% sure if it is commonly used to describe this.

Anyway, I would say it is still optimization, you're just not optimizing the same thing (size vs readability/usability). So if you can't find the proper antonym you're looking for, you can still try to express things this way.